# Finding a real-analytic diffeomorphism

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology

Let $U_1\subset \mathbb R^3$ be a simply connected bounded open set with a smooth boundary and let $U_2$ be a neighborhood of $U_1$. Does there exist a real-analytic diffeomorphism $\psi: U_2 \to W_2$ for some $W_2\subset \mathbb R^3$ such that
$$ \psi(U_1) \subset B \subset \psi(U_2)$$
where $B$ is the unit ball centered at the origin?

Comment: Is it assumed that $\overline{U_1}$ is homeomorphic to a closed ball? (I don't know the exact definition of the word "domain" in this context). Because if $U_1$ is for example a solid torus, then the answer to the question is negative (there are loops in $U_1$ which are not nulhomotopic in $U_2$ for $U_2$ small enough nhood of $U_1$).

Comment: Let's indeed assume that $U_1$ is simply connected and even with smooth boundary if it helps in any way.

Comment: Ali — are you allowing U_1 to be something like the subset of points (x,y,z) in 3-space defined by the conditions a) x > 1/2 and b)  ⃦(x,y,z) - (K,L,M)  ⃦ > 1/10 for all integer points (K,L,M) ?  This is simply connected with smooth boundary.

Comment: What do you mean by a domain?

Comment: I clarified the question.

Comment: I'm guessing that you would like the closure of U_1 to be contained in U_2. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is positive. First, the fact that $U_1$ is simply connected implies that every connected component $S_i$ ($1\le i\le n$) of its smooth boundary $\partial U_1$ is diffeomorphic to the $2$-sphere (not completely obvious, but true). Second, after the Schönfliess theorem in dimension $3$, each of these $2$-spheres bounds a domain $D_i$ smoothly ($C^\infty$) diffeomorphic with the compact $3$-ball. Since $U_1$ is bounded and connected, it is easy to conclude that one of these ball domains, say $D_1$, contains $U_1$. So, $U_1$ is the complement of $D_2\cup\dots\cup D_n$ in the interior of $D_1$. Now, any smooth diffeomorphism $D_1\to B$ is isotopic to the identity (by "Alexander's trick") and hence extends to a global smooth diffeomorphism $\phi:R^3\to R^3$. This provides a positive answer to your question but with instead of $\psi$ a diffeomorphism $(1-\epsilon)\phi$ which is only smooth. I guess that $U_2$ is bounded. Hence, the Whitney approximation theorem gives on some neighborhood of $\bar U_2$ a real analytic $\psi$ arbitrarily close to $(1-\epsilon)\phi$
in the $C^1$ topology (i.e. at every point $x\in\bar U_2$, the value $\psi(x)$ and the three partial derivates $\partial \psi/\partial x(x)$, $\partial \psi/\partial y(x)$, $\partial \psi/\partial z(x)$ are close to those of $(1-\epsilon)\phi$.) If close enough, then $\psi$ still restricts to an embedding $U_2\to R^3$ (as one sees using the local inversion theorem) and satisfies your demand.